# Firebase/ReactJS: Get only data that falls within a time frame

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

My firebase realtime database uses a cloud function to add a timestamp to an object whenever a new object is created.

How can I use this timestamp to get all objects that fall within a week or a month? Not merely `timestamp - 7 days` or `timestamp - 30 days`, but the actual week (Sunday to Saturday) or the actual month (Feb 1-28) as it appears on a calendar.

Any ideas?